# NETBEANS - How to make radio buttons match background image

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using a netbeans jFrame form, and i have inserted a Background image/ THe only problem i have is that i don't know how to get the color/theme of the radio button to be the same as my background image.
Any Tips ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
setOpaque(false);
```

This will prevent the background of the JRadioButton being drawn, thus revealing whatever is in the background.

[image]

```
JRadioButton rdb1 = new JRadioButton("RDB1");
rdb1.setOpaque(false);
```

I set the first radiobutton (RDB1) with `rdb1.setOpaque(false)` and this is what you will get.